# OLEAUT32.dll error randomly when running the application

Tags: windows, windows-7, vb6

The application works fine on Win XP, however, it comes with errors on Win7. 
The OLEAUT32.dll errors exist randomly when running my vb6 application. I have searched for solutions online, some point out that it is about the virus infection on the DLL, but I have done virus scan for the file and it is all fine. What other causes can result in these errors?
Thank you.

```
Faulting application name: MyVB6Application.exe, version: 8.0.0.0, time stamp:     0x52036491
Faulting module name: OLEAUT32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17676, time stamp: 0x4e58702a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001e0e0
Faulting process id: 0x11b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cea56cb2092596
Faulting application path: (MyVB6Application path)
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
Report Id: fbb81d53-115f-11e3-bc50-0026b9cf26e6
```

Comment: Do you use Sysmantec Endpoint Protection? Here it was causing the same error in the same DLL but in IE8, it was caused by its internet explorer addon.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very general error, and you'll need to investigate it further, unfortunately.

There's two possible solutions:

1. If you have VB6 installed and you are using the debugger, you can slowly step through the code and see where it in fact actually crashes.  This will give you insight on the issue and you can likely resolve it by changing the way things are setup.
2. If you have access to Visual C++ or WinDbg, you can actually click "Debug this application" or whatever it's called, when the crash happens, and open it up in a debugger like that.  If you have the appropriate .pdb file, you'll actually see VB6 code and have the same insight mentioend above.  This method is sometimes far quicker if you are not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: I found that this problem often occurs on Windows 7 64bit, but did not exist on Windows 7 32bit. Would it be some hints for debugging? BTW, when the problem occurs, I tried to turn on VB6 to debug the application, but it works fine when I open the application through debug mode.

Comment: Just follow my #2 suggestion - which requires it to be in EXE form anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Sysmantec Endpoint Protection (SEP)?

I just faced the same error but with a third party website which uses that DLL. It was causing IE8 to crash and force close that tab/window. We found out that it was caused by the SEP Internet Exporer Addon.

There are also some similar reports with another module from SEP for desktop applications: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mGAm4stnBBcJ:www.symantec.com/business/support/index%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DTECH202006+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us